# Change the Color of marked cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to mark some cells of a datagrid to change the color of the marked cells. I can do this with them code for a single cell:

```
    public static DataGridRow GetRow(this DataGrid dataGrid, int index)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            dataGrid.UpdateLayout();
            dataGrid.ScrollIntoView(dataGrid.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }

    public static int GetRowIdx(this DataGrid dataGrid, DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
    {
        // Use reflection to get DataGridCell.RowDataItem property value.
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(cellInfo.Item);
        if (row == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("Fehler: Keine Index gefunden da DataGridRow null!");
        return row.GetIndex();
    }



   public static DataGridCell GetCurrentCell(this DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        int row = GetRowIdx(dataGrid, dataGrid.CurrentCell);
        int column = dataGrid.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex;

        return GetCell(dataGrid, row, column);
    }
```

the calling:

```
    DataGridCell currentCell = DataGridExtension.GetCurrentCell(dataGrid1);
    currentCell.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
```

Someone know how to change this code, so that i can mark for example 5 cells and change their color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a collection of DataGridCell's and mark them all on another event, like clicking a button:

```
List<DataGridCell> CellList = new List<DataGridCell>();
```

Then whenever you click on a cell make that event add the cell to the CellList:

```
DataGridCell currentCell = DataGridExtension.GetCurrentCell(dataGrid1);
CellList.Add(currentCell);
```

Then when you want to change all the cells to the new color, click on a button and add this to the event handler:

```
foreach (DataGridCell cell in CellList)
{
    cell.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
}
```